# Small sample sizes and transfer learning

Tags: random-forest, small-sample, transfer-learning, omics

I have a very small dataset (n = 18) of patients with certain key data as well as imaging. I have performed a clustering analysis (via PCA and hierarchical clustering) to cluster these patients based on their key data, and then have created a random forest model using their imaging to predict this key cluster with good accuracy using 5-fold, 10-fold, and LOOCV. I then have used this RF model on another dataset's imaging from a different institution (n = 70) to predict this key cluster for these new patients, and then have compared certain outcomes between these groups based on the predicted cluster. I have significant results, but I am concerned at the small sample size my RF is based on. What is the standard in the literature? Note that for my original cohort, the kind of data collected is quite unique and difficult to get.

Comment: Standard for what in what literature?

Comment: Fair, I suppose the standard in metabolomics data, and specifically tumor-tissue metabolomics

Comment: Again: standard for what?  How to analyze data? How many patients to include in a study? How to apply results to a new study? How to assess whether results are significant?  Something else?

Comment: I suppose what I am asking is from the perspective of an editor at a journal, would the n for my RF classifier be considered too small to merit sending out to reviewers? I have reached significance from a " means are different" perspective in an external cohort as part of this study, but I come from a medical and coding background and not machine learning, I have to wonder if a RF trained/validated on ~18 patients' highly dimensional metabolic data would be considered valid. I suppose I'm just not sure how confident I should be in my approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say what is 'standard' because it depends on the field, data, the nature of measurement, and other details about the specific problem. In general, though, 18 individuals seems very low and I'd be highly sceptical. My scepticism would also extend to the clustering results, not just the machine learning layered on top of that. If you have strong evidence that the results generalise to a new dataset, then that would go some way towards addressing criticisms. But merely identifying the same cluster in a different dataset and finding statistical differences between this cluster and the rest of the data is very weak evidence, in my opinion.

It's worth thinking about whether you can analyse the data with a simpler and more robust alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My understanding is that the nature of hierarchical clustering/PCA is such that it doesn't necessarily extend to a different dataset?

Comment: @neriticzone You'll need to elaborate on that to get a good answer. It's certainly possible to apply a PCA from one dataset to another, though you'd need to be careful about interpretation. But either way, that probably merits a new question, as it is a bit different from the topic of this one.